# How can I access the data in a nested array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm looping through some data. Here's the JSX: For now I'm using console.log to figure out how to access the data.

```
      <div>
        <ul>
          {orderData &&
            orderData.map(item => {
              return <Order item={item} />;
            })}
        </ul>
      </div>
```

```
export default function workorder({ item }) {
  console.log(
    Object.values(item.data).map(item => {
      return item;
    })
  );

  return <h1></h1>;
}
```

Right now,

```
console.log(
    Object.values(item.data).map(item => {
      return item;
    })
  );
```

returns this, which is what I want:

[image]

**I can easily access the values inside all of the arrays excepting the first one**, with something like `item.name` or `item.email`

But the question is: how can I access the data inside of `Array(20)`? I want to render data such as deadline or description.

[image]

Attempting: `item.deadline` returns this:

[image]

So what should I be doing here?

Answer (score 0):

I belive "item" is an array, and you will want to access the array using item[0] to get an individual item. (between 0 and 19 to access individual items in the array).

It also looks like an array inside of an array, so you will have to access it twice.

So what you will want to do is use `item[0][0].deadline` to get the deadline property of the first object.

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives me `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: so .map() is going to create a new array. It might be less confusing if you assigned the new array to a new variable?

Comment: Can you tell me what happens for this code? `const tempArray = Object.values(item.data).map(item => { return item; }); console.log(tempArray);`

Comment: I get the same result.. :(